# How does a positive temperature coefficient thermistor work? (in terms of charge carriers)

Tags: electricity, thermoelectricity

I was wondering how a positive temperature coefficient (**PTC**) *thermistor* works in terms of **charge carriers**.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by understanding what PTC means.  When you have a positive temperature coefficient, it means that the given property is **increased**.  In the case of a "thermistor" (which is a resistor who's resistance varies due to temperature changes), it means that its resistance increases as its temperature increases. When you apply a voltage across the thermistor, its  current will be determined by the **effective** resistance it has at its current temperature.  With a constant voltage, its current will be a "reflection" of the temperature variations.  As the temperature increases, the resistance increases and the current decreases, and vise versa.